# Including Shared Memory BOOST Libraries in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I installed BOOST 1.57 to allow me to use some new features, so I simply created a directory at `/usr/local/boost` which contains the root BOOST folders.

I have managed to create the example code shown [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html) and compile it using:

```
 g++ example.cpp -o example -lrt
```

Here is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Ph2_ACF
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++11 debug

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -g -O1 -w -pedantic -fPIC -std=c++11 -lrt `root-config --cflags --evelibs` -Wcpp

LIBS += -L../lib -lPh2_Interface -lPh2_Description -lPh2_System -lPh2_Tools -lPh2_Utils
LIBS += $(LibraryPaths:%=-L%) -uhal `root-config --glibs`

LIBS += -L/usr/lib/ -lqjson
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qjson/
INCLUDEPATH += $(ROOTSYS)/include

INCLUDEPATH += /../../Ph2DAQ_dev/
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/boost
LIBS += -L/usr/local/boost/libs
```

And here is my error:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib -o Ph2_ACF main.o mainview.o startup.o setuptab.o setuptabviewmanager.o settings.o systemcontroller.o cbcregisterstab.o cbcregviewmanager.o provider.o aboutbox.o systemcontrollerworker.o cbcregisters.o mainviewmanager.o cbcregisterworker.o tbrowsertab.o calibrate.o hybridtest.o hybridtestworker.o hybridtestviewmanager.o hybridtesttab.o moc_mainview.o moc_startup.o moc_setuptab.o moc_setuptabviewmanager.o moc_settings.o moc_systemcontroller.o moc_cbcregisterstab.o moc_cbcregviewmanager.o moc_aboutbox.o moc_systemcontrollerworker.o moc_cbcregisters.o moc_mainviewmanager.o moc_cbcregisterworker.o moc_tbrowsertab.o moc_calibrate.o moc_hybridtest.o moc_hybridtestworker.o moc_hybridtestviewmanager.o moc_hybridtesttab.o qrc_Resources.o    -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib -L/usr/include/boost -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_regex -L../lib -lPh2_Interface -lPh2_Description -lPh2_System -lPh2_Tools -lPh2_Utils -L/opt/cactus/lib -lcactus_extern_pugixml -lcactus_uhal_log -lcactus_uhal_grammars -lcactus_uhal_uhal  -uhal `root-config --glibs` -L/usr/lib/ -lqjson -L/usr/local/boost/libs -lQtGui -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtCore -lpthread 
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libdl.so when searching for -ldl
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libdl.a when searching for -ldl
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libm.so when searching for -lm
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libm.a when searching for -lm
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libc.so when searching for -lc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib//libc.a when searching for -lc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: hybridtestworker.o: undefined reference to symbol 'shm_open@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: note: 'shm_open@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib64/librt.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/librt.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Ph2_ACF] Error 1
```

Just to note all the previous `skipping` warnings were fine before, it's just this final `'shm_open@@GLIBC_2.2.5'` which seems to break it.

All I've added is:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>

// SNIP !

using namespace boost::interprocess;

// SNIP !

shared_memory_object shm_obj
        (
            create_only                  //only create
           ,"shared_memory"              //name
           ,read_write                   //read-write mode
           );
```

Into one of my files.

Any idea what is going on?

EDIT:

Adding:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/boost/libs -lrt
```

Gives me the new error:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: mainview.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: note: '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv' is defined in DSO /opt/cactus/lib/libboost_system.so.1.48.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/opt/cactus/lib/libboost_system.so.1.48.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Ph2_ACF] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you added `-lrt` to the compile flags, and they're not being included at the link stage.

Try adding `-lrt -lboost_system` to the `LIBS` variable (like `-lPh2_Description` and the rest)

Comment: You also need `-lboost_system` in the same way (possibly more) (funny, I don't recall ever needing that for _just_ using `shared_memory_object`)

Comment: it worked, thanks. Feel free to 1up me if the formatting of the question was good

Comment: Asking for votes doesn't really work. I upvote questions when I think they're well-asked and/or they have value for  other visitors. It's especially the last part that makes SO work. (It's not so much that you can ask when you get stuck. More often, that you can find what others have done to get unstuck in the past)

Comment: I tried looking up this answer but couldn't find the answer. Since usually my questions are regarded as not very useful like the one above, I had a warning saying I would be blocked from asking questions soon hence why I just needed this one off upvote. Even if I don't use SO that often

Comment: You won't ever get banned from the site from asking useless-to-others questions. You'll only get question-banned if you post multiple actively downvoted questions. This would mean that they're actually badly asked, or completely unfit for SO. Improve the questions.

Comment: You have my upvote for this question, as it is is a reasonably asked question, and it's possible to answer from the information given. It's not terribly likely to be useful to others, but then again, there is a chance that people will find it useful. It _can_ be found.